# Returning the Max value of a half the composite key MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to query a table that has a composite key made up of two integers. The relationship is  [image]

What I am trying to get as a result is for every conversation that has been started, I want the MAX(threadNum) from the messages table. Currently the query is

```
SELECT c.conversation_id 
FROM conversation as c
INNER JOIN (
SELECT MAX(threadNum), user_from, user_to, message, dateTime, deleted,replied
FROM messages
GROUP BY conversation_id
) as m ON c.conversation_id = m.conversation_Id
WHERE (m.user_to ='$userId' OR m.user_from ='$userId') AND m.deleted = 0
```

The results that I am expecting for the conversation_Id and the threadNum would be : 
35 5
34 4
33 55

one result for every conversation_Id and only the largest threadNum result. Currently I am getting a m.converation_Id is an unknown column. What is wrong with the query structure? And more importantly is there an easier way to do what I am attempting to do?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want one row per conversation, along with the latest message in the conversation (that is, the message that has the greatest `thread_id`).

If so, that's a top-1-per-group problem. You can solve it by filtering with a correlated subquery:

```
select c.*, m.*
from conversation c
inner join messages m on m.conversation_id = c.conversation_id
where m.thread_num = (
    select max(m1.thread_num)
    from messages m1
    where 
        m1.conversation_id = m.conversation_id
        and m.deleted = 0
        and :user_id in (m.user_from, m.user_to)
)
```

`:user_id` represents the query parameter for your query (you should use a parameterized query instead of munging the variable into the query string).

Alternatively, if you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        c.*, 
        m.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by c.conversation order by m.thread_num desc) rn
    from conversation c
    inner join messages m on m.conversation_id = c.conversation_id
    where m.deleted = 0 and :user_id in (m.user_from, m.user_to)
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you. Correlated queries are something that is killing me for this project (student project in a php course reaching beyond what I know of sql). I have integrated this in and have it semi working, but am only returning 1 row. That being the MAX value from the inner query for threadNum.